# Can I use SNS subscription with internal ALB endpoint within the VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-elb, amazon-vpc

I have an SNS uses an HTTP subscription, the endpoint is an application load balancer which is created as an internal ALB within the VPC.

For SNS to call the endpoint I have to make the endpoint publicly available, I can't make the endpoint public just for SNS as my other use cases are getting addressed within the VPC.

Is there a better way to create a subscription without having to make the endpoint public.

I have for now made the endpoint public, but cant keep it the same forever

Is there a better way to create a subscription without having to make the endpoint public.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to subscribe a Lambda function (deployed in your VPC) to proxy the request to your internal ALB.

See [Using AWS Lambda with Amazon SNS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sns.html) for an exemple of event that your function will receive.

Note that it won't be possible to configure a custom [Delivery Retry Policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/DeliveryPolicies.html) like you can when using HTTP/HTTPS endpoints. Instead you will have the basic [AWS Lambda Retry Behavior](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/retries-on-errors.html).

Comment: AWS Lambda if deployed in a VPC if takes additional time to assign IP i.e ENI attachment time can take seconds in a cold start.... this will add further latency to the response for service

Comment: You could keep your Lambda function warm by calling it on a regular basis (CloudWatch Event).

Comment: Lambda is an expensive option if you consider processing millions of request per minute.